# Unterschied zwischen "einbläuen" und "eintrichtern"

Tags: difference

> **eintrichtern**-  *jemandem mit Mühe etwas, was er lernen oder beherzigen soll, einprägen* 
>    **einbläuen** - *durch ständige, eindringliche Wiederholung beibringen*

Quelle: Duden

Gibt es Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben?

Comment: **Eintrichtern** kommt vom *Nürnberger Trichter*, während **einbläuen** vom Rohrstock kommt, mit dem die Schüler früher geschlagen wurden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **einbläuen**

ist die Schreibweise für das nicht mehr gültige `einbleuen`. Dies war eine Ableitung des Verbs bleuen = schlagen mit dem Präfix `ein-`. Siehe auch:[Frühneuhochdeutsches Wörterbuch](https://fwb-online.de/lemma/bleuen.s.3vu)

*Meine Interpretation:* Im Kontext mit sehr alter Erziehungsmethodik  auch mit körperlicher Gewalt verbunden (Schlägen).

> **eintrichtern**

Beispiel: Die historische Schulweisheit, die man mir **eingetrichtert** hatte, fiel wie Schuppen von meinen Augen.

*Meine Interpretation:* Im Kontext mit heutiger Pädagogik als eine für beide Seiten lästige "Wiederholung" bei der Vermittlung von Bildung und Erziehung zu sehen (hauptsächlich von Kindern und Jugendlichen).